# OctoberCMS registerNavigation wrong status of current active submenu link

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

I have been using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/)([Builder Plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder)) to create different plugins, which works well.

I have a plugin called as **Partners** and in **Plugin.php** file code , I have below code.

**Plugin.php** code

```
public function registerNavigation()
    {
        return [
            'modules' => [
                'label'       => 'Modules',
                'url'         => Backend::url('technobrave/partners/partners'),
                'icon'        => 'icon-bars',
                'permissions' => ['Technobrave.Partner.*'],

                'sideMenu'    => [
                    'partner' => [
                            'label' => 'Partners',
                            'icon'        => 'icon-thumbs-up',
                            'url'         => Backend::url('technobrave/partners/partners'),
                            'permissions' => ['Technobrave.Partner.*']

                    ],
                    'team' => [
                            'label' => 'Team',
                            'icon'        => 'icon-group',
                            'url'         => Backend::url('technobrave/team/team'),
                            'permissions' => ['Technobrave.Team.*']
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
```

And here below is my **Partners.php** *controller* file code

**Partners.php** controller code

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();             
        BackendMenu::setContext('Technobrave.Partners', 'modules', 'team');
    }
```

Everything works fine apart from my current **active** class, even if I am on the **Partners** page, it is still selecting "Team" as current menu link. Below is the screen shot with browser URL for better understanding.

[image]

As you can see above, I am on **Partners** page still its showing current active URL as **Team** page. Can someone help me how to handle this ?

Thanks

PS: Added `PHP` tag if someone tag just for the shake of help I need if someone knows and had ever come across using this CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the menu context for each controller.
For the `Partners.php` use this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();             
    BackendMenu::setContext('Technobrave.Partners', 'modules', 'partner');
}
```

And for the `Team.php` use this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();             
    BackendMenu::setContext('Technobrave.Partners', 'modules', 'team');
}
```

Comment: Sry, I missed the fact that your main menu item was called partners also.
The second argument for the `setContext` function takes the parent item url and the third one should be the page url

Comment: Ok, check the latest edit. I checked my own `plugin.php` for reference and this should be better